# Spring JPA - How to force custom order of repository calls within a transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Data JPA 1.11.6.RELEASE, I have the following trouble;

With a simple 1-to-n relationship between them, I have `TableA`, and `TableB`, where `A` contains multiple `B`. And I have the repository of `TableB` with custom delete method;

```
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<TableB, String> {
    @Modifying
    void deleteByTableA(TableA tableA);
}
```

where it deletes with the FK value, that is the PK of `TableA`

In my service class, I use these;

```
@Service
public class TheService {

    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BRepository bRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void deleteInsert(List<TableB> bList) {
        TableA tableA = aRepository.findByEtc(...);
        bRepository.deleteByTableA(tableA);
        bRepository.save(bList);
    }
}
```

But the issue is that the order of the operations inside `@Transactional` method changes according to the optimization done by Hibernate. Thus causing some unique constraint violations, in case I have the duplicate entities of `TableB` exist in the new table. If I put a `bRepository.count()` call between delete & save calls, this forces my custom order, but I'd like to achieve this with some configuration rather than such silly tricks. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the answer to your problem lies in [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/def/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions%28org.hibernate.event.EventSource%29) about order of flush operation. According to Hibernate JavaDocs the SQL operations order is:

- inserts
- updates
- deletions of collections elements
- inserts of the collection elements
- deletes

You may want to flush it manually after the first operation:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteInsert(List<TableB> bList) {
    TableA tableA = aRepository.findByEtc(...);
    bRepository.deleteByTableA(tableA);
    bRepository.flush();

    bRepository.save(bList);
}
```

Or try to replace "delete + insert" operation with an update operation.

Comment: Thank you, I did try this also, but with an `EntityManeger.flush()`, it was not working, but with repositories flush it does work. Still, though, I am annoyed, can't I force this through an annotation on `deleteByTableA` method? I just do not wish to have a manual flush call amidst the logic steps.

Comment: I have never heard of such possibility in Hibernate.

Comment: I agree with Rafal, you have to manually flush the persistence context to make the delete happen before you insert an object with the same key. It should be possible to use `EntityManager.flush()`, if your repository extends JpaRepository, you can also call `JpaRepository.flush()`

Comment: By the way, about the replace "delete + insert" with an update operation, could you give an example on that? I thought `save` method would only affect the entities in the parameter, not the remaining ones that I'd like to delete.

Comment: @bureaquete What I meant was: try not to delete + insert but perform an update using one-to-many relation you most likely have on your entities. It may be less performant though.